# Copy data for each user using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, copy, directory

I have a text file with a list of user names separated by semi colon, users names in the text file are: user1; user2; user3, etc.. The user names all have a network folder located at \testserver\users\user1, \testserver\users\user2, and so on.

I am trying to have PowerShell script read the text file and copy the folder and all data in each folder for each user from one location to another location called \testserver\newusers\users. However when I launch the script I have written so far, it just creates a folder with a user name from the text file I have. Below is what I have so far:

```
$File = Get-Content .\MyFile.txt
$File | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Split(';') | ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path "$_" -Destination '\\testserver\newusers\users'
    }
}
```

I am launching my PowerShell .ps1 file from a location that has the myfile.txt file in it.

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Call `Copy-Item` with the parameter `-Recurse` if you want to copy the folders' content as well. Otherwise just the folder itself would be copied (without content). You also need to provide the full path to the source folders unless you run the script from `\\testserver\users`.

Something like this should work:

```
$server = 'testserver'
$src = "\\$server\users"
$dst = "\\$server\newusers"

(Get-Content .\MyFile.txt) -split ';' | % {
  Copy-Item -Path "$src\$_" -Destination "$dst\" -Recurse
}
```